# How to find distances from an array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have an array of dates (1000 columns,2 arrows).

Link of the data: https://mega.nz/#!MMlhWbbT!bwsu4_t98hLNX-A7IYnWipPydtWILkKxgMzXhu3ytHE

I want to calculate the distances (without repeating or counting twice). I am using,

```
def D(x1,x2,y1,y2):
    return math.sqrt((x2-x1)**2+(y2-y1)**2)  

x1=dt1[0][0]
x2=dt1[1][0]
y1=dt1[0][1]
y2=dt1[1][1]
print(D(x1,x2,y1,y2))
```

But there are 1000 points, how I can determine the distance using a for or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will calculate the distance between two consecutive points over the whole array:

```
for x in range(0,len(dt1)):
    print(D(dt1[x][0],dt1[x+1][0],dt1[x][1],dt1[x+1][1]))
```

If you want to calculate the distance between any two points in the array without repetitions, this should do it (includes the new request by the OP):

```
distances = []
for x in range(0,len(dt1)):
    for y in range(x+1,len(dt1)):
        dist = D(dt1[x][0],dt1[y][0],dt1[x][1],dt1[y][1])
        distances.append(dist)
print(distances)
```

Comment: How I can store the array results?

Comment: I edited the answer to include storing the results in an array

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.linalg.norm` to compute Euclidean distance:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: dt1 = np.random.rand(2, 2)

In [3]: dt1
Out[3]:
array([[0.79791459, 0.71415415],
       [0.52647092, 0.894041  ]])

In [4]: np.linalg.norm(dt1[0] - dt1[1])
Out[4]: 0.3256392880558975
```